# Why Swiper JS arrows begin to work after I move a slide with a swipe and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I got swiper-js slider that's opens in a modal window. The arrows doesn't work until I drag(even a slight drag is enough) a photo left of right. After that everything is ok. I've added "observer: true";
"observeParents: true" parameters to the code - that doesn't solve the issue.  Need some help!

```
HTML:
      <div id="overlay" class="hidden">
        <div class="swiper-container modal-preview-gallery">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
             <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img src="./img/bigger/${fileName}" alt="" />
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img src="./img/bigger/${fileName}" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img src="./img/bigger/${fileName}" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-button-next overlay-arrow"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>

        </div>
      </div>

CSS: 
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #607a68c5;
}

.modal-preview-gallery {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.modal-preview-gallery .swiper-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

JS: 
      photo.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
         modalPreviewSwiper.slideTo(
          +e.target.parentElement.dataset.swiperSlideIndex + 1
         );
        toogleGallery();
       };
       
      let modalPreviewSwiper = new Swiper(".modal-preview-gallery", {
       loop: true,
       navigation: {
       nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
       prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
       },
       observer: true,
       observeParents: true,
      });

     modalPreviewSwiper.update();
```

Comment: A code snippet would help to identify the issue better.

Comment: I added a snippet, hope this would help.

Comment: Try setting `touchEventsTarget: 'wrapper'`

Comment: I have the same issue, anyone can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to spend a lot of time looking for a solution to this problem.
I noticed that classes have been added to the buttons

```
.swiper-button-lock
.swiper-button-disabled
```

so I just changed the classes through the settings

```
swiper = new Swiper('.utps', {
    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 1.1,
            centeredSlides: true,
            spaceBetween: 40,
            navigation: {
                lockClass: 'lolo',// class that turns off buttons
                disabledClass: 'uh',// class that makes buttons inactive
                nextEl: ".swiper-button-next.utps-butt",
                prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev.utps-butt",
            }
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 67,
        }
    }
});
```